# тут должно отбавляться из переменой hpzomb переменная dam при попадание объекта с тэгом "bullet" но этого не происходит. Объясните почему?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public float dam = 10;
public float hpzomb = 100f;

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col){
    if (col.tag == "bullet") {
        hpzomb = hpzomb - dam;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ну например потому, что условие не срабатывает

Answer (score 1):

Частые причины не работы тригера:

**1.** Проверьте, включена ли у вас галочка на против "Trigger", во свойстве BoxCollider2D

**2.** Проверьте тэг, возможно у вас где-то есть заглавные буквы, они тоже учитываются. Например: `Bullet` и `bullet` - это совершенно два разных тэга

**3.** Проверьте, стоит ли у вас Rigidbody 2D на объекте с триггером, если нужды в Rigidbody 2D нету, то во вкладке Freeze, поставьте галочки на против всех пунктов

Comment: надо было в Unity в Edit=>Project Settings=>Physics2D включить взаимодействие между объектом и тем объектом который попадает в него